# convert mysql resultset into a (name, data) object to be fed into HighCharts

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, highcharts

I am using [HighCharts Bar graph](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic) to plot data from mysql resultset into a bar graph.

Now the resultset of my query is as below:

```
Name       Expense
-----------------
July       700.0000
August     450.0000  
September  1700.0000
```

The `series` property of HighCharts require data in below format to plot the graph

```
[
 {name:"July",data:[700.0000]},
 {name:"August",data:[450.0000]},
 {name:"September",data:[1700.0000]}
]
```

So I thought of coverting my resultset into a JSON object using `json_encode($row)`.
But I got the following output:

```
[{"name":"July","data":"700.0000"},
 {"name":"August","data":"450.0000"},
 {"name":"September","data":"1700.0000"}]
```

**Doubts:**

1. Is there a way to get/convert the resultset in exactly the same format as is required by the series property of HighCharts?
2. Also can I use an object of created in the php block, directly into the javascript? Say I create an object `$jsonNameData` out of my resultset. Then can I use it in the javascript as

   `series: <? echo $jsonNameData ?>`

**EDIT:**

I was able to solve Q1 by doing the following:

```
$count = 0;
$strSeries = "[";
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   if($count == 0){
       $strSeries .= "{name:'" . $r['name'] . "',";
       $strSeries .= "data:[" . $r['data'] . ']}';
       $count = 1;
   }
   else {
       $strSeries .= ",{name:'" . $r['name'] . "',";
       $strSeries .= "data:[" . $r['data'] . ']}';
   }
 $rows[] = $r;
}
$strSeries .= "]";
```

Got the required string into `$strSeries`.

Now the problem is the second question. I assigned the value of `$strSeries` to a variable in javascript but when I use that variable as

```
series: variableName
```

It is not plotting the graph properly even though the variable has proper value (checked through alert).

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one, post them separately

Comment: Compare as well: [`JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-numeric-check) (int) Encodes numeric strings as numbers as flag for [`json_encode(php)`](https://php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not got a chance to run the code below, but this should work or something very similar to this

```
$series=array();
while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $serie=array(
     "name" => $item['name'],
     "data" => array(floatval($item['data']))
  );
  array_push($series,$serie);
}
echo json_encode($series);
```

An advice is to always stick to [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for doing the jsonification. You may want to go through [this example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#example-3493) on the reference page to learn about how json_encode works with arrays in particular

**EDIT:** To answer your 2nd question. You may be getting a highchart error #14 in the javascript console? Have a look at this question [Highcharts returning error 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485560/highcharts-returning-error-14)

*P.S. Please don't mix multiple questions in one, post them separately, also use tools like javascript console and SO search more effectively*

Answer (score 0):

I would try this :

```
$jsonObj = '[';
foreach($mysqlResul as $item){
    $jsonObj .= '{"name":"'.$item['name'].'","data":['.$item['data'].']},';
}
// strip off last comma
$jsonObj = substr(0,strlen($jsonObj)-1,$jsonObj);
$jsonObj .= ']';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat('{name:"', name, '",data:[', expense, ']}') as foo
from bar
```