# Javascript basic issue regarding passing parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to load a chart using HighCharts.

I've created a function that takes the relevant data and creates a new garph, If I manually take the data and hardcode it instead of using the parameters to pass the info everything works great, but I'm not sure what's wrong with the way I'm passing them:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4GBNQ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were passing the data as strings, it needs to be passed as an array, like this:

```
createGraph(
    "3333",
    "123123",
    ['04/10/2012','05/10/2012','06/10/2012','07/10/2012','08/10/2012','09/10/2012'],
    [98,98,97,96,96,94]
);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4GBNQ/1/)

Comment: you may want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485560/highcharts-returning-error-14/12489695#12489695

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
createGraph("3333","123123",['04/10/2012','05/10/2012','06/10/2012','07/10/2012','08/10/2012','09/10/2012'],[98,98,97,96,96,94]);
```

});

if you observe, i have removed "" for your arrays