# How to dynamically add Series of data to line chart using high chart

Tags: c#, jquery, highcharts

The data from webservice is got from BindTrend method and it is parsed to Json object before binding to the chart:
My code is as follows:

```
 var plot;
    var itemdata = [];
    var chart;
    var data = [];
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ChartBinder.asmx/BindTrend",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {           
               var newJ = $.parseJSON(msg.d);               
                DrawTrend(newJ);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });    
    })   

    function DrawTrend(plot) {
       for (i = 0; i < plot.length; i++) {
        var x = {}
        x.id=plot[i].Name;
        x.name = plot[i].Name;
        x.data = [plot[i].Value];
        itemdata.push(x);
        }
              chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            series: itemdata
        });
    }
```

Please note when I hardcode the values `'x.data=[1,2,3....]'`, I am able to get the chart.
Kindly help.

Comment: can you `console.log(plot[i].Value)` for me please?

Comment: @Jugal: The value of 'plot[i].Value' is ["3121", "21211", "3121", "21211", "21000", "9872", "83402", "83402", "28302", "109523", "2832", "9523"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you mentioned in the comment, looks like your plot[i].Value is an array of `Strings`, it should be array of numbers/floats. You can do the conversion in javascript as follows. Also no need to add `[` & `]` around the value explicitly, a JS array has it in it by default.

```
   for (i = 0; i < plot.length; i++) {
        var x = {}
        x.id=plot[i].Name;
        x.name = plot[i].Name;

        //plot[i].Value = ["3121", "21211", "3121", "21211", "21000", "9872", "83402", "83402", "28302", "109523", "2832", "9523"];

        var stringArr=plot[i].Value;
        var floatArr=[];
        for(var j=0;j<stringArr.length;j++){
           dobleArr.push(parseFloat(stringArr[j]);
        }
        x.data=floatArr;

        itemdata.push(x);
   }
```

I would suggest going through [Highcharts returning error 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485560/highcharts-returning-error-14/12489695#12489695) as well

Comment: Thanks, console.log() helped me to identify the mistake. I corrected the string object in the class and converted it to int.

Answer (score -1):

is that because you declare x in 'for' ?

```
 var x = {}
 function DrawTrend(plot) {
       for (i = 0; i < plot.length; i++) {

        x.id=plot[i].Name;
        x.name = plot[i].Name;
        x.data = [plot[i].Value];
        itemdata.push(x);
        }
```

Comment: `x` is only used inside the `for` loop, why should you declare it outside? Once the value of `x` is pushed into `itemdata`, it can & should be destroyed as it is no longer needed, declaring inside the for does this for us