# Having Issue on Rendering Highchart from MySQL JSON Output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

I am having issue on loading json Data from a table to highchart.js column type. I tried to load the JSON to JavaScript object and access them like :   `y:  chartvals.projects` but I got this error message:

> Uncaught Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14

what I have is this ajax call and highchart snippet:

```
var req2 = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "assets/tempchart.php"
});
req2.done(function(data) {
    var chartvals = data;
    $('#chart1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Economy Model',
            style: {
                color: '#5882FA',
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                fontSize: '11',
                marginBottom: '30'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Total Projects']
        },
        yAxis: {
            tickInterval: 50,
            max: 800
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.x +
                        ' is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
            }
        },
        series: [{
                data: [{
                        name: 'Point 1',
                        color: '#00FF00',
                        y: chartvals.projects
                    }]
            }]
    });
});
```

Can you please let me know how to fix this? Thanks

> Update

Here is the Response JSON

```
{"project":"8","powerline":"188.396496","road":"7.876766","cost":"69885005.45"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when string value is sent to series.data, but it expects number.
This happens if you pass in a string as a data point.

[**HightCharts Error # 14**](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14)

> Highcharts expects the data values to be numbers. The most common reason for this is that data is parsed from CSV or from a XML source, and the implementer forgot to run parseFloat on the parsed value.
>
> For performance reasons internal type casting is not performed, and only the first value is checked (since 2.3).

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, but how about solution? do you have any idea hoe to fix the issue?

Comment: you have to pass integer value instead of string

Comment: can you post the reponse json in your post??

Comment: post your json reponse.

Comment: yes in the y:  chartvals.projects - Data for series

Comment: see this , if it helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485560/highcharts-returning-error-14

Comment: yeah, I already saw this but couldn't figure it out how it works! Thanks any way

Comment: i used high charts in one project and made a tutorial see here:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/09/bar-charts-and-graphs-in-aspnet-mvc.html